# Javascript .click Listener Firing on DOM Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this simple JS code that performs AJAX requests when certain HTML elements are clicked. At least, that's what it's suppose to do. For some reason, every URL that I have listed is being fired as soon as the page loads, and not when the elements are clicked

```
function challenge_stuff(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        success:function(result){
            $("#challenge_stuff").html(result);
        }
    });
}

$("#cancel").click(challenge_stuff("../cancel_challenge"));
$("#accept").click(challenge_stuff("../accept_challenge"));
$("#decline").click(challenge_stuff("../decline_challenge"));
$("#wonMatch").click(challenge_stuff("../won_match"));
$("#lostMatch").click(challenge_stuff("../lost_match"));
$("#confirm_win").click(challenge_stuff("../confirm_win"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  your function to this, and you're all set:

```
function challenge_stuff(url) {
    // v---return your handler!
    return function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            success:function(result){
                $("#challenge_stuff").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now it returns a function that will be assigned as the handler. This is more convenient than manually adding an anonymous function to each call.

---

While this part can stay the same:

```
$("#cancel").click(challenge_stuff("../cancel_challenge"));
$("#accept").click(challenge_stuff("../accept_challenge"));
$("#decline").click(challenge_stuff("../decline_challenge"));
$("#wonMatch").click(challenge_stuff("../won_match"));
$("#lostMatch").click(challenge_stuff("../lost_match"));
$("#confirm_win").click(challenge_stuff("../confirm_win"));
```

you could shorten it a bit like this:

```
var ids = {
    cancel: "cancel_challenge",
    accept: "accept_challenge",
    decline: "decline_challenge",
    wonMatch: "won_match",
    lostMatch: "lost_match",
    confirm_win: "confirm_win"
}
$.each(ids, function(id, url) {
    $("#" + id).click(challenge_stuff("../" + url));
});
```

---

Could be even shorter if the ID and the url directory shared the same name. Then you could use an array, and use the same value in both places.

```
// Make sure the ID and path are set up to be identical
var id_path = ["cancel","accept","decline","won_match","lost_match","confirm_win"];
$.each(id_path, function(_, id) {
    $("#" + id).click(challenge_stuff("../" + id));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$("#cancel").click(function() {challenge_stuff("../cancel_challenge")});
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the result of `challenge_stuff` function execution, not the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the appropriate argument to the `challenge_stuff` function:

```
$("#cancel").click(challenge_stuff.bind(null, "../cancel_challenge"));
$("#accept").click(challenge_stuff.bind(null, "../accept_challenge"));
$("#decline").click(challenge_stuff.bind(null, "../decline_challenge"));
$("#wonMatch").click(challenge_stuff.bind(null, "../won_match"));
$("#lostMatch").click(challenge_stuff.bind(null, "../lost_match"));
$("#confirm_win").click(challenge_stuff.bind(null, "../confirm_win"));
```

However, I think that a more sensible approach would be:

```
function challenge_stuff() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        success:function(result){
            $("#challenge_stuff").html(result);
        }
    });
}

$('.challenge-btn').click(challenge_stuff);
```

And in your HTML:

```
<a class="challenge-btn" data-url="../cancel_challenge">Cancel</a>
<a class="challenge-btn" data-url="../accept_challenge">Accept</a>
<a class="challenge-btn" data-url="../decline_challenge">Decline</a>
<a class="challenge-btn" data-url="../won_match">Won Match</a>
<a class="challenge-btn" data-url="../lost_match">Lost Match</a>
<a class="challenge-btn" data-url="../confirm_win">Confirm Win</a>
```